# Swagger yaml file items must be an object error

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-3.0

I converted my jsonschema that works in the script to YAML format for swagger documentation. The issue is that in line 8 (-type: string) swagger shows error: should be object, 'items' must be an object.

```
      type: object
      properties:
        answers:
          type: array
          minItems: 4
          maxItems: 4
          items:
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Yes', 'No']
```

Json schema

```
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "answers": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Not really", "Slightly", "Significantly"]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Not really", "Slightly", "Significantly"]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Not really", "Slightly", "Significantly"]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Yes", "No"]
                    },

                ],
                "minItems": 4,
                "maxItems": 4,
            }
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It because `items` should be an object (i.e. YAML mapping) but you give an array (i.e. YAML sequence).

You probably want to use `prefixItems` because you seem to want to validate the array as tuple:

```yaml
        answers:
          type: array
          minItems: 4
          maxItems: 4
          prefixItems:
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Not really', 'Slightly', 'Significantly']
            - type: string
              enum: ['Yes', 'No']
```

[See docs:](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html)

> In Draft 4 - 2019-09, tuple validation was handled by an alternate form of the items keyword. When items was an array of schemas instead of a single schema, it behaved the way prefixItems behaves.